# Does `jobject` always have the same address if it represents the same Java instance?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, native, jniwrapper

Given a java object `A a = new A()`, and a bunch of native instance methods, if I were to take the address of the `jobject` representing `a` passed into those methods, **would the address always be the same?**

I have multiple final fields in these classes that I want to store in a hashmap in my C code (so I don't have to continue fetching them with `Get___Field`), with the hash of a `jobject` being the address. If I can guarantee that the address of a passed in `jobject` representing `a` will always be the same, then the hash is deterministic, which means my program's behavior will not be inconsistent.

Comment: If you want to retain a reference to any object across multiple jni calls, you need to call NewGlobalRef. http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/native1.1/implementing/refs.html. However, although that guarantees that the reference you hold remains valid, I don’t know if it guarantees that subsequent references passed in will match.

Comment: @prl I've looked through that, but calling `NewGlobalRef` gives a global reference that can be assigned to a global variable, it doesn't seem to change whether the passed in `jobject` is global or local. Based on my current understanding, the passed in `jobject` is not something I construct and determine the locality of, the JVM constructs it and passes it in.

Comment: In a similar situation, I stored an “object id” (the hash) in the object. I had Java pass in the id as an additional parameter to the native method.

Comment: @prl I might as well pass in the values of the final instance fields (and dropping the idea of a global hashmap in the C code) if I opt in for passing in additional parameters, would this be more performant than fetching the values within the C code through the JNI interface?

Comment: @prl If I made a static native method (which would be used in place of a constructor), that returns a global reference to a `jobject` (that represents the java instance), do you know if all the other `jobject`s that I would receive in my native instance methods would be equivalent to this global reference?

Comment: Thee, I don’t know. It seems likely to me.

Comment: If you are going to use object references across JNI calls, you need NewGlobalRef (or NewWeakGlobalRef and then for each use, NewLocalRef). Otherwise, you won't be able to tell if your cached value is a still a valid object reference. And, no, a new reference is, well, a different reference, even for the same object. They are roots in the garbage collection system.

Comment: @TomBlodget so with this idea, I would still receive local references to the objects (through the method arguments), but I would just ignore them in favor of my cached global reference?

Comment: I'm just saying if you have a cache system it has to keep JNI global references. How you would do a lookup, I don't know. Perhaps a linear search using IsSameObject if you can't add an object identity field to each class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As comments have suggested, you cannot keep the passed-in `jobject` around beyond the current JNI call context because it is a local reference. The `jobject` values may be reused (leading to duplicate table entries) or become invalid. Furthermore, each call to `CreateGlobalRef()` will create a new, distinct `jobject`. The short answer is "you cannot do it this way". Such has been already addressed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31209999/android-jni-c-code-always-get-same-jobject-value-for-2-different-surfaceview). As an alternative approach, note that every Java Object has a `hashCode()` and `equals()` method.  You *can* call those methods from your C/C++ code using JNI, and use them in your hash table. However, without knowing the details of when and how you are fetching the field values, calling JNI methods may not be any better than fetching the field values again.

Finally, as answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26239773/comparing-jni-object-references), you can test `jobject` equality directly using `env->IsSameObject(jobject1, jobject2)`.  Presumably, `jobject1` is the *global* reference that you have created and stored, whereas `jobject2` is the passed-in *local* reference that you want to test against. Unfortunately this still doesn't help you probe into your hash table.

Comment: If I made a static native factory method that returns a global `jobject`, would that object still not be passed in to the instance native methods?

Comment: I don't think so.  Anything passed *from* java *to* C/C++ is going to get a brand new local reference.